# Why do my builds fail after installing a pod?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I installed a pod (which went fine) but when I try building my .xcworkspace it would fail, regardless of whether I imported the pod in the code or not.

This is the error I get:

```
error build: Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '.../Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework/GoogleMapsBase' for architecture arm64
```

I've found what seems like the exact problem [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685059). The solution proposed here is to update the library.

I tried

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

but what I got was

```
error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to try the same method as the image below?

`Build Settings` -> `Architectures` -> `Excluded Architectures`, `arm64`.

[image]

Comment: does the interface have to be as a storyboard? Because all of the videos I've seen so far on pods have that as the interface

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a `Storyboard` or a `SwiftUI`.

Comment: This is a problem that occurs with your MacBook's architecture (M1 <-> Intel).

Comment: Just had the time to test this and it works! Thank you loads